# If someone hacked into my Gmail account, wouldn't that let them go in and change my recovery email all together?

Tags: gmail, password-recovery

So what is the point of a recovery email? Shouldn't my recovery email be secret?

Comment: Have you tried changing the recovery email? Presumably, Gmail would send a message there.

Comment: I feel you bro! But maybe a better similar question would be [*"What's the point of recovery security questions?"*](http://www.cregox.com/blog/2014/05/are-you-programmer-do-you-want-to.html) because **those** are indeed not only useless, but also broken and insecure. For an answer to your question, @Jerry got it perfectly right. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a recovery email is not to retake an account that was broken into. As [Google documents:](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183723?hl=en)

> We'll use your recovery email address to communicate with you under
>   these circumstances:
>
> • We need to confirm your username after you create an address
>     • You can't sign in to Google
>     • You've forgotten your password
>     • You're about to run out of storage space
>     • We need to alert you to any unusual activity involving your address

Comment: Someone breaking into it and changing the recovery email falls into the last category "We need to alert you to any unusual activity involving your address".

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change any sensitive data, any service provider would ensure that its legitimate user performing that to avoid misuse and total loss.

Some of them choose to delay the application for such operations, like the new values get updated only after a certain time span.

Other use a double check approach and you get an alert on your alternate channels like you will get an email plus SMS in case of Google account sensitive info change. There they also include info to prevent that change in case you haven't requested those .